# Does Azure load balancer allow connection draining

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I cant seem to find any documentation for it.

If connection draining is not available how is one supposed to do zero-downtime deployments?

Answer (score 2):

[Rick Rainey](https://serverfault.com/users/237896/rick-rainey) answered [essentially the same question](https://serverfault.com/questions/686095/gracefully-take-a-server-out-of-azure-load-balancer-drain-stop/686995#686995) on Server Fault.  He states:

> The recommended way to do this is to have a custom health probe in
>   your load balanced set. For example, you could have a simple
>   **healthcheck.html** page on each of your VM's (in wwwroot for example)
>   and direct the probe from your load balanced set to this page. As long
>   as the probe can retrieve that page (HTTP 200), the Azure load
>   balancer will keep sending user requests to the VM.
>
> When you need to update a VM, then you can simply rename the
>   **healthcheck.html** to a different name such as **_healthcheck.html**. This
>   will cause the probe to start receiving HTTP 404 errors and will take
>   that machine out of the load balanced rotation because it is not
>   getting HTTP 200. Existing connections will continue to be serviced
>   but the Azure LB will stop sending new requests to the VM.
>
> After your updates on the VM have been completed, rename
>   **_healthcheck.html** back to **healthcheck.html**. The Azure LB probe will start getting HTTP 200 responses and as a result start sending
>   requests to this VM again.
>
> Repeat this for each VM in the load balanced set.

Note, however, that Kevin Williamson from Microsoft states in his MSDN blog post [Heartbeats, Recovery, and the Load Balancer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/02/28/heartbeats-recovery-and-the-load-balancer.aspx), "Make sure your probe path is not a simple HTML page, but actually includes logic to determine your service health (eg. Try to connect to your SQL database)."  So you may actually want an aspx page that can check several factors, including a custom "drain" flag you put somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your clients need to simply retry.

The load balancer only forwards a request to an instance that is alive (determined by pings), it doesn't keep track of the connections. So if you have long-standing connections, it is your responsibility to clean them up on restart events or leave it to the OS to clean them up on restarts (which is obviously not gracefully in most of the cases).

Zero-downtime means that you'll always be able to reach an instance that is alive, nothing more- it gives you no guarantees on long running requests.

Comment: But it should, IMO.
Go tell the users' browsers to retry the download.

Comment: @AndréCruz I agree ;) But that's the state right now, I can tell you that there is something in the Azure product pipe that might help here.

Comment: +1 for mentioning very important part about established connections - `So if you have long-standing connections, it is your responsibility to clean them up on restart events or leave it to the OS to clean them up on restarts (which is obviously not gracefully in most of the cases).` I have seen some people think setting LB persistence to `None` (5-tuple) means every HTTP request will be balanced between backend pool instances. Which is not true if client has already established TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when a probe is down, only new connections will go to other VMs
Existing connections are not impacted.